# Ajax to php retrieving formdata

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, multipartform-data

I'm sending my files through vue.js to my laravel backend but I'm not able to retrieve the data correctly.

Vue.js :

```
<b-form-file
    v-model="files"
    :state="Boolean(files)"
    placeholder="Choisissez un fichier..."
    drop-placeholder="Glisser ici..."
    multiple
    accept=".jpg, .png"
    class="textOverflow"
    name="file[]"
></b-form-file>
```

Ajax :

```
onSubmit(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    for( var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){

        let file = this.files[i];

        formData.append("filePos: "+ i, file, this.id);
    }

    axios.post('/pictures', formData, 
    {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'} })
    .then((res) => { 
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Laravel php :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $images = $request->all();

    info($images);
}
```

So this gives me :

```
[2020-04-26 15:40:48] local.INFO: array (
  'filePos:_0' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => '25',
     'mimeType' => 'image/png',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)  
[2020-04-26 15:40:50] local.INFO: array (
  'filePos:_0' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => '25',
     'mimeType' => 'image/png',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

Which is perfect, but I can't retrieve specific data like if I just want the originalName and do ->request('name'), I can the weird chain of characters as if I wasn't the correct encoding.

Does someone know how to retrieve specific information for separating the images, manipulate them and so.

Thanks for reading

Edit :

If I use dd instead of info :

```
array:1 [
  "filePos:_0" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#343
    -test: false
    -originalName: "25"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\Users\Gian\AppData\Local\Temp"
    filename: "phpEC28.tmp"
    basename: "phpEC28.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\Users\Gian\AppData\Local\Temp\phpEC28.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "C:\Users\Gian\AppData\Local\Temp\phpEC28.tmp"
    aTime: 2020-04-26 16:28:39
    mTime: 2020-04-26 16:28:39
    cTime: 2020-04-26 16:28:39
    inode: 35184372088948345
    size: 109758
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\Users\Gian\AppData\Local\Temp\phpEC28.tmp"
  }
]
```